# Can I stop Dropbox from automatically updating itself on OS X?

Tags: dropbox

Dropbox seems to auto-update itself on OS X. Problem is that the latest version of Dropbox doesn't support OS X 10.10.0 which I have to run for compatibility with other apps.

I tried re.installing an older version of Dropbox, which then works for a few minutes before it updates itself again.

Is there a way to stop Dropbox from updating itself so I can stay with an older version of Dropbox?

Answer (score 1):

Your may try moving it from `/Applications/` to `/Applications/Utilities`. Dropbox does not automatically updates when I keep it in `Utilities` folder.

Comment: This suggestion worked for me, but when I double clicked the dropbox icon inside the utilities folder nothing would happen.... however if you right click and show package contents, and > contents > MacOS > dropbox that will open, and so far it has not tried to upgrade!

Comment: When I did this, Dropbox launched okay and so far hasn't updated, but: 1. I have to keep the Terminal window open and 2. the Terminal window reports an error `NSFCString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking`.

Comment: Correction. It still updated even when running from inside package contents. Then quit. I'm now looking at https://www.pcloud.com/ (20GB free)